# package xkeyval Error

Tags: listings

I wrote the following code in Latex overleaf editor.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, basicstyle=\small, caption=Table 9: Program of 'selfdestruct', obtained from [333].]
```

The image is given below:

[image: Undefined in families 'lst']

I have removed comma from caption but still I am getting warning message and last ']' bracket i not shown, see the command below:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, basicstyle=\small, caption=Program of ''selfdestruct'' obtained from [333].]
```

The image2 is given below:
[image: Warning message Image 2 not getting last square bracket]

I am now using the curly brackets:

```
\begin{lstlisting}{language=Python, basicstyle=\small, caption=Program of ''selfdestruct'' obtained from [333].}
```

but I am getting the error message which is shown below in image3:

The image3 is given below:
[image: missing end cs name]

Somebody please guide me

Zulfi.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use braces around the caption: `\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, basicstyle=\small, caption={Table 9: Program of 'selfdestruct', obtained from [333].}]`, otherwise the `,` in the text is misinterpreted as a separator for the key-value list.

Comment: Please see image 2 above, I have removed the comma from the "caption" but now I am getting a warning message and the last ']' is not visible.

Comment: Kind of the same issue. Now the `]` in `[333]` is seen as the delimiter for the optional argument of `\begin{lstlisting}`.  Really, you should use the braces rather around that. It's the proper way to solve the problem. When using key-value arguments you always have to add braces around arguments that contain `,` or `[]`.

Comment: I have enclosed in curly brackets but still I am getting error message, kindly see the image3.

Comment: No, the optional argument _must_ be in square brackets, like it was before, but the _value_ of the `caption` option should be in braces.  Please, copy the following to your document and it will work: `\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, basicstyle=\small, caption={Table 9: Program of 'selfdestruct', obtained from [333].}]`